# ARM Assembly - what's the difference between v1 and a1 registers?

Tags: assembly, arm, cpu-registers

I'm currently playing around with the arm simulator called armulator. While looking at some small programs I see registers v1 and a1 being used. What's the difference between the two?

Comment: The difference is that they refer to different registers, which is hopefully apparent on account of them not being the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're really asking "what do the 'a' and 'v' mean?", and answer that instead.

The [procedure call standard](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042f/IHI0042F_aapcs.pdf) designates some registers as being primarily for "arguments" and "variables", and permits referring to them as such by synonyms:

```
register  synonym
 r0        a1
 r1        a2
 r2        a3
 r3        a4
 r4        v1
 r5        v2
 r6        v3
 r7        v4
 r8        v5
 r9        v6
 r10       v7
 r11       v8
```

Comment: And personally, I think they are an awful idea and just make things far harder to read than the architectural register names, especially with being 1-indexed.

Answer (score 1):

- `a`=**A**rgument = `Parameter`
- `v`=**V**ariable

about ARM register arch and call convention which containing `a` and `v`, I have summarized some, list here for you refer:

- [image]

  - [online view](https://www.processon.com/view/link/6295e1b80791294815547608)