# ARM assembly code understanding and conversion

Tags: assembly, arm

I've been trying to figure out the following code... I know that this is the solution: the code implements a recursive function on the elements of a vector that is passed in one of the registers while the size is passed in the other one, however I can't seem to understand how to get to it.

```
    s_r:
ADD SP, SP, -8
BNE A1, 0, ALTRO
ADD V1, 0, 0
ADD SP, SP, 8
MOV R15,R14

ALTRO:
ADD A1, A1, -1
LSL R8, A1, 2
ADD R8, R8, A2
LDR R8, [R8]
STR RA, [SP,4]
STR R8, [SP]

BL s_r

LDR R8, [SP]
LDR RA, [SP+4]
ADD SP, SP, 8
ADD V1, R8, V1
MOV R15,R14
```

I think that I understand all of the instructions happening individually, only thing I'm not certain of that of LDR R8,[R8] . I read somewhere on stack that it is equal of len(r8) meaning that it is an array? I'm also confused on all adds because they don't use # which means that -8 is not a number but a what? I thought that add sp,sp,-8  "make spaces for 2 more  on stack" . Is this a mistake? Even if this was a mistake I get something like this when I try to decipher it :

```
#it's a function?
some function:
    while(a1!=0):
        a1=a1-1
        r8=a1*4+a2
        r8=get an element of an array
        push (r8,ra)
    v1=v1+0
    load r8 and ra from stack ( last values)
    pop them from stack
    v1=r8+v1
    return
```

As far as I can understand it is taking elements out of an array( starting from the last) and placing it into stack together with RA, which I don't understand what that is? The biggest problem is that whatever I do I get a kind of a loop instead of recursive function

If anyone has any ideas or tips, anything is appreciated since I can't find solutions anywhere and I've been stuck on it .

Comment: `LDR R8, [R8]` is a load instruction.  It uses R8 as an address (i.e. a pointer), loads a word from that address in memory, and then overwrites R8 with the value that was loaded.  Are you familiar in general with pointers and pointer arithmetic?

Comment: `ADD SP, SP, -8` is just the same as `ADD SP, SP, #-8`.  With some assemblers the `#` is optional.   You are right that it allocates two words of space on the stack.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thank you so much for these 2 commnets it triggered a lot of things that   I've connected to it because of it ! I'm so so with pointers. However I edited a bit because ur comment made me realise some things like that it is taking elements address offset and then taking base to get to an element ( if I'm not mistaken). Do you perhaps know what does RA do here or what is RA in general?

Comment: No, I don't know about RA.  ARM's registers are R0 through R15, with A1-A4 and V1-V8 being aliases, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40516646/arm-assembly-whats-the-difference-between-v1-and-a1-registers.  My assembler doesn't accept RA and I am wondering if it might be a typo.  Or maybe some assembler accepts RA as an alias for R10 or something, with A in hex being 10?

Comment: Do you have any information about what assembler this code was meant to be built with?

Comment: @NateEldredge thank you for info once again it indeed could be R10 I would've never hought of that, sadly no I do not have any information, all I was told that : 
a lot of directives relative to the data memory allocation  (data or program), constants  are canceled and sometimes specific to the particular compiler chosen. Sadly, no specific information.

Comment: Actually, from the context my best guess is that `RA` is somehow the link register `R14`.  It's saved and restored around the recursive call, which would need to be done for the link register, but it isn't otherwise used in any way.  Is it possible that somebody defined it as a macro for `R14` or `LR`?

Comment: As for your "loop versus recursion", remember that `BL` is a subroutine call: it saves the program counter in the link register before branching.  So within the call, when the function returns by doing `MOV R15, R14` (remember `R15 = PC` and `R14 = LR`), it returns back to the instruction following `BL s_r`.

Comment: @NateEldredge hm,  regarding RA  and the "solution I was given"  ( "recursive function on the elements of a vector that is passed in one of the registers while the size is passed in the other on"). Since R8 is for element it would mean that RA is then used for size (however I don't understand how since no operations are done with RA).  Regarding the "loop vs recursion", correct me if I'm wrong but Add sp,sp,-8 is done first then it jumps to altro which is being done until there are no more elements(jumping to s_r then back to altro due to bne).

Comment: @NateEldredge When there are no more elements, s_r is done fully ( I don't understand the point of Add v1,0,0 it acomplishes nothing?)  but by mov r15,14 I'm moved 1 line after BL s_r since that is where my PC is stored? It would mean that then there it loads last 2 values of a stock and pops it off. And then again ADD V1,R8,V1 I don't understand what it means. **Last Mov r15,r14,** where does it take me, does it take me somewhere where this whole code was called. or is that where I'm getting "recursion" that I'm not seeing?